# Adding textInput choice into my dataframe in shiny, and able to select it again instead of re-typing

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app, if the user selects the "other" radio button,that could type it in but also saved in the backend for the user does not have to retype it when they select the "other" radio button again.

Tried to use UpdateSelectInput function.

```
radioButtons(inputId = "Id", label = "Select Id ",inline = TRUE,
                     choices = list("choice 1", "choice 2","OTHER"), selected = "choice 1"),

uiOutput("sub_choices")

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$sub_choices<- renderUI({
    if(input$Id== "choice 1"){
      selectInput(inputId="sub_Ids",
                  label="Select sub Ids",
                  choices = list("sub choice 1", "sub choice 2" , "sub choice 3", selected = "")

    }else if(input$Id == "choice 2"){
      selectInput(inputId="sub_Ids",
                  label="Select sub Ids",
                  choices = list("sub choice 1", "sub choice 2" , "sub choice 3", selected = "")
    }else{
      textInput(inputId = "other_choice", label = "Type Other",
                value = "")
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the text from `input$other_choice` as a `reactiveVal` and use again.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "Id", label = "Select Id ",inline = TRUE,
               choices = list("choice 1", "choice 2","OTHER"), selected = "choice 1"),
  uiOutput("sub_choices")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  rv <- reactiveVal("")

  observe({
    rv(input$other_choice)
  })

  output$sub_choices <- renderUI({

    if (input$Id == "choice 1") {
      selectInput(inputId="sub_Ids",
                  label="Select sub Ids",
                  choices = list("sub choice 1", "sub choice 2", "sub choice 3", selected = ""))
    } else if(input$Id == "choice 2"){
      selectInput(inputId="sub_Ids",
                  label="Select sub Ids",
                  choices = list("sub choice 1", "sub choice 2" , "sub choice 3", selected = ""))
    } else{
      textInput(inputId = "other_choice", label = "Type Other",
                value = rv())
    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

When one can use `conditionalPanel` instead of `renderUI`, I prefer `conditionalPanel`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "Id", label = "Select Id ",inline = TRUE,
               choices = list("choice 1", "choice 2", "OTHER"), selected = "choice 1"),
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.Id === 'choice 1' || input.Id === 'choice 2'",
    selectInput(inputId="sub_Ids",
                label="Select sub Ids",
                choices = list("sub choice 1", "sub choice 2", "sub choice 3"))
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.Id === 'OTHER'",
    textInput(inputId = "other_choice", label = "Type Other",
              value = "")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```